# CKEditor custom plugin for RapidSpell throws error on IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ckeditor

I created a custom plugin for RapidSpell using the code below.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('spell',
    {
        init: function (editor) {
            editor.addCommand('spell', {
                exec: function (editor) {
                    rapidSpell.ayt_aytEnabled = false;
                    spell('cke_contents_Model_NoteText', 'dialog');
                }
            });

            editor.ui.addButton('spell', {
                label: 'Spell Check',
                command: 'spell',
                icon: this.path + 'icons/spell.png'
            });
        }
});

function spell(id, mode) {
    var ifr = document.getElementsByClassName('cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset')[0];
    ifr.setAttribute('id', id + '_ifr');
    ifr.id = id + '_ifr';

    if (mode == 'dialog')
        rapidSpell.dialog_spellCheck(true, ifr.id);
    else
        rapidSpell.ayt_spellCheck(ifr.id);
}
```

It works fine in IE 9 but throws a Javascript Error in IE 8. I am using CKEditor 4 that is suppsoed to be compatible with IE8 as well. So I am wondering where the issue is.

> Message: Object doesn’t support this property or method
>    Line: 21
>    Char: 5
>    Code: 0
>    URI: https://btsdebasctk01.wrbts.ads.wrberkley.com/Library/Scripts/ckeditor4/plugins/inlinespell/plugin.js?t=E0LB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for [the `getElementsByClassName` function](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname) was added in IE9.

If you don't need to support anything earlier than IE8, use [`querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) instead.

If you need to support IE7 or earlier, use a polyfill such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607), or a library which supports this functionality such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: For those looking for specifics, change

var ifr = document.getElementsByClassName('cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset')[0];

to

var ifr = document.querySelectorAll('.cke_wysiwyg_frame.cke_reset')[0];